# Google maps api v3 hide gray building overlays

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am making a map that can display several trains live driving around inside the station. However there is a grayed out building on top of the station that makes the tracks almost impossible to see. However when I look at google maps itself those buildings don't even appear. Is there a setting in the map options that I can implement to get rid of those buildings?

These are my existing map options:

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    center: markerBounds.getCenter(),
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    scrollwheel: false,
    draggable: false,
    navigationControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

My map:

[image: This is my map]

Google maps:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to fix the issue. Simply change

```
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
```

to

```
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
```